# Nginx proxied webmin still requesting over HTTP

Tags: nginx, proxypass, webmin

I have a webmin installation that is proxied by an nginx server.

My nginx config looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name mysite;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;

    ## Your website name goes here.
    server_name mysite;
    location / { 
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:10000/;
        proxy_redirect  http://127.0.0.1:10000/ https://mysite/;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    }  
}
```

Everything works except for some parts of webmin where I get a:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mysite/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 'http://mysite/useradmin/index.cgi?mode=users'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

I have also tried to set the **Redirect non-SSL requests to SSL mode?** to yes but without success.

Comment: Probably you have to fix your application

Comment: As Alexey says, the links are in your application, not in your webserver config. Fix your application.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a cache problem. Try a private/incognito window or a different browser and see if the problem persists.

If it does you can try adding these headers to your `location` block:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Ssl         on;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       https;
```

Comment: It still doesn't work I think it is probably hardcoded into webmin.